# c++How to use utf-8 and/or utf-32 in c++ without wchar without stuff like ICU (gcc/cl compilers)?

Tags: c++, unicode, utf-8, c++20, utf-32

I have tried many things but they don't seem to work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "en-US.utf8");
    std::string uni = u8"ユチエフー８";
    std::cout << uni;

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;

}
```

Please note that I want utf-8/utf-32 to work not in just this situation but most of the situations without using things like wide characters.

Comment: _"without using things like wide characters"_ That's probably the least thing you need to realize that anyways.

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: That UTF encoding has hothing to do with wide (Ansi) chars.

Comment: i know that, but about everyone is telling me to use them
but i am not exactly comfortable with 2 bytes on windows and 4 bytes on linux
that is why I specified that I dont want wchars.

Comment: UTF encoding doesn't have anything to do with windows Ansi wide chars either. If you need to convert these encodings from one in an other format you'll have to use an appropriate 3rd party library (or windows API functions), which can do this for you. The c++ standard, and locales in particular do completely different (an in your case orthogonal) things.